How to achieve excel like formulas with AG-Grid Angular
Can someone suggest how to achieve excel like formulas with AG-Grid Angular ?
Precisely, feasibility of achieving excel like formulas with AG-Grid Angular native ?
If not, how to achieve, do we have any third party plugin available for this.
